# Which Desktop prevails? (Running OneDrive Personal & OneDrive for Business, with Desktop syncing.)

Tags: windows, sync, onedrive

I am confused about "Desktops" here.

It appears I will have three Deskstops in the following setup, if I have OneDrive syncing Desktop folders:

- OneDrive Personal Desktop
- OneDrive for Business Desktop
- Local PC Desktop

Can someone break this down for me?

My direct question would be, how do I control which Desktop on each of my PCs/latops (I have 4, only 1 is business) is connected to each OneDrive?

Comment: We recently got this answer from MS: it's forbidden to use several OneDrive apps at the same time as it will cause collision. In our situation OneDrive for Business prevailed but had issues.

Comment: @Hardoman, I do not believe it is forbidden to use several OneDrive apps when they are different apps, one for business and one for personal. Plus, the OneDrive app itself lets you log into another account while you are already logged into the first.

Comment: We've got this info from MS Engineer in the support case. I believe it's a trusted source. It's not forbidden but this may corrupt the configuration at some conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own exploring, it turns out neither prevails. They both sync to each other.

So, if you only want one Desktop to prevail, then you have to disable the local Desktop syncing on the computer in question.

Here's an example:

At my work, I have both OneDrive personal and business. I only want the local Desktop at work to sync to the OneDrive business. I do not want my OneDrive personal syncing my home local Desktop to my work local Desktop (which was happening). The solution was to disable the syncing of the at-work OneDrive personal app to the Desktop. At home, I can sync the OneDrive personal app to the Desktop.

Let me know if this makes sense. Feel free to edit.